# not able to create file from linux using java

Tags: java, linux

My requirement is to read from a file placed in linux machine, change the contents of it.
For doing so, I am reading the file, creating a temporary file, writing the contents of the original file to the temporary file, then delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original name. This works well when I use it from a VM but does not work when I actually try to run it on the linux machine. 
It does not give any error. But when I go and see for the file in the path, it does not exist. Below is my code. Please suggest what might be wrong.

```
public class ReadWriteReplace {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String filepath = "/home/cloudera/Desktop/datefile1";

    File file = new File(filepath);
    File fout = File.createTempFile("tmp", "");

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fout);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    String division = "abc";
    String input = "";
    String finaldate = "2015/04/15";

    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        if (line.contains(division.toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("line :::"+ line);
            String [] line1 = line.split(",");
            System.out.println("line1[0] :::"+line1[0]);
            System.out.println("line1[1] :::"+line1[1]);

            System.out.println();
            bw.write(line1[0]+","+finaldate+'\n' );
        }else{
            bw.write(line+'\n');
        }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    br.close();
    bw.close();

    String foutstring = fout.toString();
    System.out.println("foutstring ::"+foutstring);

    FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(fout);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
    String line1 = br1.readLine();
    System.out.println("line1:::"+line1);
    while(line1 != null){
        System.out.println("br1 line ::"+line1);
        line1 = br1.readLine();
    }
    br1.close();

    File oldFile = new File(filepath);

    if(oldFile.delete()){
        System.out.println("filedeleted");
        fout.renameTo(oldFile);
    }
}
```

}

My input file has the below data:

```
mno,2015/03/14

jkl,2015/03/17

ghi,2015/03/15

abc,2015/03/18

cdf,2015/03/19
```

**EDIT::**

Just to make things clear, I am creating a jar for the above code and running it on the remote linux machine using putty.

Comment: Is your intent to replace the concrete file with the temporary file? If so, why are you using a temporary file in the first place?

Comment: Check what permissions your app is running under.

Comment: I want to change the date for 'abc'. That's my intention. For doing so, I found that above method will work. First reading the original file, change the date for 'abc' and write all the records to temp file. Now, delete the old file and rename the temp file to the oldfile name. Please let me know if there is any good way of achieving this.

Comment: @EvanKnowles, this code is reading and even deleting the file from the given path. I think it means the code has got read & write permissions. If I still need to check the permissions, please let me know how and where can I check the permissions

Comment: You didn't check whether you succeeded in renaming the file. And I strongly recommend not using `java.io.File` in this day and age, it is well known for not throwing errors when something goes wrong. Use the `java.nio.file` packages, like `Paths` and `Files`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, when I run it on a VM, I am able to see that the file is existing at the given location with changed data. But when I run the same code on the remote linux machine, the code did not give any error and when I checked for the file in the location, it does not exist.

Comment: Does your `fout.renameTo()` return `true`?

Comment: And that's exactly why you shouldn't be using `File` - because it doesn't give you any indication if something went wrong. It may be OK on your VM and wrong on your "real" machine and you don't know. As @Sinstein said, you are not even checking whether the rename succeeded. Using `java.nio.Files.move(...)` would have thrown an Exception if something went wrong.

Comment: @Sinstein I just checked that fout.renameTo() returned false. Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: @ManojKumarG Shouldn't you just pass `fout.renameTo(filepath)` instead of `fout.renameTo(oldFile)` given that you delete the `oldFile` before you rename?

Comment: @Sinstein, the renameTo() takes a File object as input, so, I had to give the oldFile while renaming. Even I tried creating another file object like File  newFile = File(filepath); and passing the newFile to the renameTo() as fout.renameTo(newFile); but it aslo returned false.

Comment: @ManojKumarG try doing a chmod 755 on the directory you're working in and the file you are trying to modify

Comment: @ConMan, I did try doing a chmod 777 on the file that I am working on but no luck.

Comment: @ManojKumarG also check you have write access to the directory you are working in /home/cloudera/Desktop

Comment: I could not find why it was not working, but I resolved this problem by creating files directly on HDFS and not on local file system. This works fine. Thanks everyone for suggesting different ways of resolving my issue.